Help identifying an old letterpress font
I got a letterpress off Ebay awhile ago but I can't seem to identify the typeface. Any ideas?


Post the screen capture, or detail of the image, not a link to a random file pls.

The typeface highlighted in the image looks very close to the classic Bookman Old Style - bold font.

